# Read a file one char at a time until newline character using read(2) and write(2)

Tags: c++, arrays, unix, buffer

I'm trying to a read text file until the first newline character is found and print out the first line up until that first newline character.

I am using the read(2) and write(2) unix system calls to complete this. Do not want to use getline() function for this. I wanted to go through each character in the buffer array and print the elements out until I get to the first newline character in the first line. Also trying to figure out to do the same for the second line and also the last line in the text file. Each line will be displayed in their own separate program if that make sense.

Here is what I have so far for the first line program....

```
#define BUFFSIZE 4
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   if(argc != 2)
   {
      cout << argv[0] << "need filename" << endl;
      exit(4);
   }

 int n = 0;
 char buf[BUFFSIZE];
 int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);

 while((n = read(fd, buf, BUFFSIZE))>0)
 {
    if[buf[0] != '\n')
     {
        cout << buf[0];
     }
    if[buf[1] != '\n')
     {
        cout << buf[1];
     }
    if[buf[2] != '\n')
     {
        cout << buf[2];
     }
    if[buf[3] != '\n')
     {
        cout << buf[3];
     }
 }
close(fd);
}
```

I am taking a input file as a command argument. I have several lines in the input text file that goes like...

```
Purple is a cool color
Blue is the color of the sky
Green is the color of the grass
```

When I run this program, it prints all the lines into one long line in command window and with no space in between each sentence.

```
Output
Purple is a cool colorBlue is the color of the skyGreen is the color of the grass
```

I want to be able to print the first line only when the first newline character is found and I am having a hard time figuring out how to print each element in the array until the newline character is read.

Comment: So? Your code literally prints each character except if it's a newline. Hence, your output consists of everything on one line. So, what exactly is your question? P.S. If the file's size is not an even multiple of four, the output will be slightly wrong.

Comment: Why do you read in `4` chars at a time? Why not just read in `1` char at a time?

Comment: My question is that how do I print each element in the array until the first newline character is found in the first line? My program is printing all the lines into one line in output.

Comment: I was trying to read blocks of data at one time.

Comment: @Nicole Internally the `read()` function will read the file in blocks for efficiency. I just thought it would simplify the program reading just one char at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The way your program is formed you are literally telling it to print everything until a newline char is found, and when one is found to omit it.
Introduce an `else` for those `if !=` where you print whatever it is that you want in place of newline (e.g. 2x newline).

The listing also seems malformed (conditionals followed by a square bracket), but I assume that's typos. It's always best to post code that will compile when asking for help.

Also as posted in comments you are reading 4-at-a-time with no conditionals, you will eventually get into a crash or garbage input.